# Directory filenames with sed with whitespaces

Tags: shell, directory, sed, find

I'm working on a script and I'm stuck, even with the help of the google.

Here's my code:

```
for FOLDER in `find . -type d | sed "s#^.#$(pwd)#" | sed 's/ /\ /g'`
do
    echo "$FOLDER"
done
```

This will replace only the first instance of " " with "\ " but not the rest.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about structuring your command that way and use `find -execdir` instead:

```
find . -type d -execdir sh -c 'pwd' \;
```

Or use zsh:

```
for d in **/*(/); do
  echo $d
done
```

Comment: The first command cut off a lot of paths in the output but the zsh command worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xargs` instead of a loop for executing the same command on a list of elements. There are options to take care of whitespaces.

Comment: Add `-print0` to the `find` command, and specify `-0` to `xargs`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are complicating everything.

Maybe you only need this:

```
find $(pwd) -type d | sed 's/ /\\ /g'
```